# Running FULLTEXT searches is returning no result

Tags: mysql

OK here is my query which I'm running in php my admin.

There are records which should match, e.g. War Dog, War Hog, Warrior. If I search 'War' I get nothing. If I search for other things, 'Dwarf' I get matches with Dwarf in the title. It seems 'War' and 'War Dog' don't want to match, not sure why.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `searchable_products`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `searchable_products` SELECT * FROM content_product;
ALTER TABLE `searchable_products` ENGINE = MYISAM;
ALTER TABLE `searchable_products` ADD FULLTEXT(`productTitle`);
SELECT *, MATCH (`productTitle`) AGAINST ('war') AS `relevance` FROM `searchable_products` WHERE MATCH (`productTitle`) AGAINST ('war') ORDER BY `relevance` DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: For performance reason, by default the fulltext search will not index any words less then four characters long – if you have access to the server config, you can change that, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: right, but that doesn't explain why it doesn't match war dog (which is seven characters long)...

Comment: No, that’s two words that are three characters long each.

Comment: right :) I see. So I need to tweak the config...